# Change Database records sort order to move record position in between other records with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a Project management PHP/MySQL/JavaScript app which has **Project Task Lists** which have **Task records**.

A Tak list name/heading is nothing more than a Task record with a database column that indicated it is to be used as a heading/list name and then Task records can be organized under separate Task list based on there **sort order database column**

So based on the demo below that consists of **17 Task records** and **3 are Task Lists records**

```
ID  | TASK NAME          | Sort Order
01  | - Task list 1      | 1
02  | --- task item 1    | 2
03  | --- task item 2    | 3
04  | --- task item 3    | 4
05  | --- task item 4    | 5
06  | --- task item 5    | 6
07  | - Task list 2      | 7
08  | --- task item 6    | 8
09  | --- task item 7    | 9
10  | --- task item 8    | 10
11  | --- task item 9    | 11
12  | --- task item 10   | 12
13  | - Task list 3      | 13
14  | --- task item 11   | 14
15  | --- task item 12   | 15
16  | --- task item 13   | 16
17  | --- task item 14   | 17
18  | --- task item 15   | 18
```

So consider the scenario where I want to update `task item 13` which is `ID = 16` and `sort order 16` and update its sort order so that it "Moves" the Task record to `Task List 1`

I would like to have a simple to use PHP function to complete this type of job of moving a Task record to a new sort order so that it shows up under a new Task list like this:

```
/**
 * Move Task record to new Task List by ID
 * $taskId int Task ID number
 * $taskListId int Task List record ID number
 */
$task->moveTaskIdToListId($taskId, $taskListId);
```

**I would appreciate any help please as I am not sure how to do this exactly?**

After some thought here is what I think might be involved...

**Possible steps to complete moving Task records to new lists**

1. To move `task item 13` from list 3 to list 1.  Query DB and get sort order value for the Next list after the one we are moving to.  So get sort order for list 2 which is 7.
2. Now Subtract -1 from list 2's sort order and that gives us the number that `task item 13`'s sort order must be changed to in order to move it to `list 1`
3. Now `task item 13` and `Task list 2 record` would both have a sort order of `7`.
4. So starting at `Task list 2` record and all records after it, would need to increment there sort order numbers by +1

Any suggestions on how to do this, doe my steps above sound about right to do this?  AGain I realize this is not the best structure to do this but I am trying to make it work on an existing system

Comment: Look at how others have managed drag drop sortables with mysql

Comment: am i mistaken or do you have one table here for multi-use with children ? ok don't do this re-jigger sort order column thing. someone out there will use it for a larger problem and be foobar'd

Comment: @DrewPierce You are correct as mention it is not the ideal best solution but in this existing project I am trying to not change it and live it for the time being.  They used 1 table for Task records and Task list/heading records.  All the records have a `sort_order` DB column in which a Task list heading is simply drag and dropped in between task records to separate and make them appear in `Lists`.  I realize the correct way is to create a new Task Lists DB table but I am interested in doing this for the time being

Comment: @Strawberry Drag and drop sortables are already working fine.  I am trying to come up with a way in code to move and reposition items in between other items all with code.

Comment: sounds like u know exactly how to do it tho. u will have a HOLE where "task item 13" was. might wanna tighten that up

Comment: @DrewPierce Thanks that is something I had overlooked!  So yeah when I started the question I had no idea but kind of worked out how it might be possible by the end of typing it all so wanted to post it anyways to get feedback and see if there might be another way or see what I missed so you already mention 1 item I missed so thanks!

Comment: @JasonDavis Your response makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Strawberry if you read the question it might make more sense.  What I am saying in response to your suggestion is that I do not need to get drag and drop sorting to work as that already works in the app.  Instead I need to be able to move the sort position of items with code programmatically just as if the user had drag and dropped the item,  No worries

Comment: Yes. I know what you're saying. If you bothered to follow my suggestion and google , say, " drag drop sortables with mysql " you would certainly find a solution to your predicament.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose this would work, but i think i'd add a column for "sort order", not messing with IDs :o and assuming you're using PDO as $this->db - i think the trick is to give the current owner of newid, a temporary id, then move the oldid to the newid, then move the tempid to oldid

```
public function moveTaskIdToListId($oldid,$newid){

$this->db->beginTransaction();
$tmpid=$this->db->query('SELECT max(`id`) FROM `table`');
++$tmpid;
$this->db->query('UPDATE `table` SET `id` = '.$this->db->quote($tmpid).' WHERE `id` = '.$this->db->quote($newid));
$this->db->query('UPDATE `table` SET `id` = '.$this->db->quote($newid).' WHERE `id` = '.$this->db->quote($oldid));
$this->db->query('UPDATE `table` SET `id` = '.$this->db->quote($oldid).' WHERE `id` = '.$this->db->quote($tmpid));
$this->db->commit();
//todo: error handling and handle case when newid does not exist yet..(if that ever happens)
}
```